# iPad writing custom apps and scripts

Tags: ipad, scripting

I have an iPad 1 with redsn0w jailbreak.

I have a little experience writing html & php and I can find my way around the command line on a Linux machine. I use PuTTY to connect to my iPad, and iOS seems to be very Linux like.

I am wondering about writing custom scripts and apps for the iPad. I did some search on Google and here on Stackoverflow, but I have come up with a blank (perhaps I am searching for wrong terms).

So on to my actual questions...

Question #1
Are there any free development platforms that let you develop and test apps for the iPad?

Question #2
Are there any free scripting languages available that will run from the iOS shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. XCode is free, but you'll need a mac. If all you're doing are web apps, there's no need for any specific compiler like XCode, so you can obviously do your development on any machine in Vi, emacs, notepad, or whatever you want.
2. According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/47295/is-it-possible-to-access-the-shell-darwin-on-an-iphone) you'll need to install MobileTerminal and some other shell utilities to do any decent bash shell scripting.
3. My own advice: save yourself a boatload of hassle and invest in a used Mac Mini on craigslist and get xCode for free and you can do all the custom (and far more capable) programming for your iPad that you could ever wish for.

Comment: Thanks for response. Q#1-I have a PC not a Mac, and since everything I would write would just be apps for myself I will not be purchasing a Mac anytime soon. Q#2-I can use PuTTY from my PC and connect to iPad. Reading that other post prompted me to look further into what Cydia actually installed on the iPad and it includes the BASH shell, so I just have to read up on that if I want to write scripts.